# How to change the URL of a clickable banner?

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven

As we all know, the twenty-eleven theme comes with a random banner feature which, if the site visitor clicks it, takes him to the home page.

So there could be quite a few different images for the banner, but they all take you to the same URL when you click them.

What I would like to have is that *each* banner image will have its *own* URL.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: even if you could override the URL, how would you propose to edit/add/change the urls from the backend?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell That's an excellent question and +1 for that. I, of course, prefer some sort of a plugin that will allow me to change the URLs from the backend, but if something like this isn't already available, then I will compromise on hacking the child theme's PHP files. Any idea which file I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you register a post type called 'header_slide' and use the featured image of said posts as the banner. Do a query with a maximum of 1 post per page and display the banner, and add the url as a custom field.

Something similar to this:

```
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'header_slide',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby ' => 'rand'
));

if($q->have_posts()){
    while($q->have_posts()){
        $q->the_post();
        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
            $url = get_post_meta($post->ID,'custom_header_link',true);
            if(empty($url)){
                $url = home_url();
            }
            echo '<a href="'.$url.'">';
            the_post_thumbnail(array(920,200)); // adjust numbers to fit desired size
            echo '</a>';
        }
    }
} else {
    // hmm no header slides were found, ABORT!!!!!! or maybe display a default
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

To generate the code for registering the `header_slide` post type, go here:

http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/

Answer the questions and it will generate a chunk of code for you at the end, put that code into your themes functions.php, and make sure it supports custom fields and featured images/post thumbnails

Comment: What a great detailed answer. If this also allows editing the URL from the backend, then I couldn't have expected a better answer than this. Now, I do have a header plugin installed which associates each page with a specific banner. Will this get in the way? BTW, my own grepping found that the URL is currently fixed at [header.php](http://lab.yukei.net/wp-trunk/nav.html?wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php.source.html) around line #74.

Comment: This solution is separate from your header plugin. You should have made us aware you already had a plugin when you asked the question. My solution is self contained, and separate

Comment: Didn't notice your link to header.php, I must point out that whatever you do, it will not be using the standard wordpress header banner API call